# Worker thread exits some time later

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

Here is a simple echo program using sockets and multi threads, it compiles and runs well in my Ubuntu if the client(via telnet) and server run on the same machine, but when I remotely connect to the server via telnet from another machine, it initially runs well(echos my message back every time), but some time later, there is no echo anymore even the telnet session is still alive, i am not sure where the problem is, can someone give some hits on this? I am new to multi thread programming and socket programming, learning on that.

```
#define ERROR       -1
#define MAX_CLIENTS 2
#define MAX_DATA    1024

void* worker(void* sockId)
{
    int socketId = *(int*)sockId;
    int data_len = 1;
    char data[MAX_DATA];
    while(data_len > 0)
    {
        data_len = recv(socketId, data, MAX_DATA, 0);
        if (data_len > 0)
        {
            send(socketId, data, data_len, 0);
            data[data_len] = '\0';
            printf("Sent message: %s", data);
        }
    }
    printf("Client disconnected\n");
    close(socketId);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        printf("missing argument: port\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    int sock;
    int new_connection;
    int sockaddr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == ERROR)
    {
        perror("server socket: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bzero(&server.sin_zero, 8);

    if ((bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sockaddr_len)) == ERROR)
    {
        perror("bind: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if ((listen(sock, MAX_CLIENTS)) == ERROR)
    {
        perror("listen: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        if ((new_connection = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &sockaddr_len)) == ERROR)
        {
            perror("accpet: ");
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("New Client connected from port: %d and IP: %s\n", ntohs(client.sin_port), inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));

        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, worker, (void*)&new_connection);
        pthread_detach(thread);
    }
    close(sock);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this compile?  new is a reserved word in c++.  Perhaps you compiled using C?

Comment: it compiled well using gcc. Yes, I should be using another name instead of new, it is a reserved word in c++.

Comment: `if (data_len)` should be `if (data_len > 0)` and `while(data_len)` should be `while(data_len > 0)`. Otherwise, you spin on an error.

Comment: When you say it stops echoing, do you mean it stops displaying the `Sent Message: ...` thing? Or do you mean it stops sending on the socket? Or both?

Comment: it stops displaying the Sent Message: ...

Comment: Ahh, then I know exactly what your problem is. See my answer.

Comment: @FrankZhang - gcc can invoke g++, but can launch c based on the file extent.  When you want C++ compiler, go ahead and  use g++.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN ok, i see. for this program, i believe gcc is ok since it is a pure c code.

Comment: @FrankZhang - probably need to change the C+ tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add some logging and you'll probably find that your code is blocked in `send`. You use naive, sequential I/O, so if the other end of the connection stops reading data, soon you do too.

Comment: this sounds make sense and i need time to validate. but a question is that why telnet from the same machine to the echo server program is always alive, the worker is also running in a new thread i believe, it can echo back even after a day.

Comment: @FrankZhang In that case, the outbound data was getting read. It may be that part of the issue is that you're connecting with telnet but you haven't implemented the [telnet protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854), so you might interoperate badly with some versions of telnet.